# Eclipse Luna version 4.4.2 not showing suggestions for java 8

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I recently installed Java 8 64 bit version on my machine and installed Eclipse Luna version 4.4.2 64 bit.However when I programme a java application,the IDE not showing auto suggestions to use Java 8 features like use lambda expressions instead of  anonymous inner class.The code I have used is given below.As my reputation is low I am not able to post images.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Run method called");

        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake,I have seen the feature in netbeans.In netbeans 8 it is showing.Wonder why eclipse not included these suggestions

Comment: Is your project set to use Java 8 Compiler compliance?

Comment: Yes it is set to Java 8 compliance level.The option is showing when we explicitly click Ctrl+1.But why it isn't showing as a bulb hint like in Netbeans as we always needed to press Ctrl+1 for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, if the absence of comfort UI feature implies that they are focusing on fixing all these compiler bugs first, I really appreciate that…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. I press Ctrl+1 when staying on `new Runnable`:
[image: Convert to lambda expression screenshot]

Seems that there's no way to mark it as warning (yellow lightbulb). However you can switch on a save action for lambda. Go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions, check "Additional actions", press "Configure", go to "Code style" tab and check the "Convert functional interface instances":

[image: Save action]

This way all the anonymous classes which can be converted to lambdas will be converted automatically upon you press Ctrl+S. You can also make this conversion for the whole project at once: select the project in Package explorer, right-click, Source, Clean up, Use custom profile, configure and check the same checkbox.

Comment: Yes it is showing suggestion while pressing Ctrl+1.But is there a way it could show as a yellow bulb hint as if in net-beans as we always needs to press Ctrl+1 to get suggestion.

Comment: @kiran_muralee, edited the answer describing other possibilities

Comment: @KiranMuralee, Eclipse users typically don't need the yellow bulb because almost every location in your program will offer some quick assist. Such visual hints are reserved for more severe issues: warnings and errors.